# DataFrame cells line breaks

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

The question is quite simple.
How could I prevent line breaks in cells of printed dataframe in **jupyter notebook** (not in terminal).

None of answers I've seen here, like those of using `pd.get_option('display.width')`, `pd.get_option('display.max_colwidth')` etc. didn't help me.

I still get this:
[image]

Comment: What values do you have in the DataFrame? Is it strings? Could line breaks be part of your strings?

Comment: Initially I have float numbers, but then I convert them by lambda function:   `thousand_separator = lambda n: '{:,.2f} р.'.format(n).replace(',', ' ')` and apply this function with method `applymap(thousand_separator)` of initial dataframe.

Comment: And for numbers which have less then 7 digits, like `9 507.23 р`, there is no line breaks in the printed dataframe.

Comment: I see that you are using non-standard theme to display your dataframe. Could this be the reason. I'm using vanilla jupyter notebook and your example works fine for me
https://imgur.com/ecRh8it

Comment: Here is example. I've created new one notebook.
There are two columns dataframe: https://imgur.com/a/mGwthkz, and nine columns https://imgur.com/a/w3RaH3s

Comment: As you can see on the second post there are line breaks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens because there is no space to render content of the cells, so `html` solution of text wrapping kicks in.
You can disable it by setting `white-space` cell property to `nowrap`:

`df.style.applymap(lambda x:'white-space:nowrap')`

or

`df.style.set_properties(**{'white-space': 'nowrap'})`

[image]