# IPython / Jupyter: how to customize the display function

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I have 3 basic problems when displaying things in IPython / JupyterLab.

(1) I have a pandas dataframe with many columns. First, I make sure I can see a decent portion of it:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=240,edgeitems=5,precision=3)
pd.set_option('display.width',1800) #number of pixels of the output
pd.set_option('display.max_columns',100) #replace the number with None to print all columns
pd.set_option('display.max_rows',10) #max_columns/max_rows sets the maximum number of columns/rows displayed when a frame is pretty-printed
pd.set_option('display.min_rows',9) #once max_rows is exceeded, min_rows determines how many rows are shown in the truncated representation
pd.set_option('display.precision',3) #number of digits in the printed float number
```

If I print it, everything gets mushed together:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yO2d1.png)
Is it possible to **print text wide**, i.e. in a way that each line (even if longer) is printed on only 1 line in output, with a slider when lines are wider than the window?

(2) If I display the mentioned dataframe, it looks really nice (has a slider), but some string entries are displayed over 4 rows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08QeT.png)

How can I make sure every **entry is displayed in 1 row**?

(3) The code below produces the output, which works fine:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=np.linspace(0.1,30,1000); 
fig,ax=plt.subplots(1, 4, constrained_layout=True, figsize=[15,2])
ax=ax.ravel()
ax[0].plot( x, np.sin(x))
ax[1].plot( x, np.log(1+x))
ax[2].plot( x, np.sin(30/x))
ax[3].plot( x, np.sin(x)*np.sin(2*x))
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdWnB.png)
However, when I change `[15,2]` to `[35,2]`, the figure will only be as wide as the window. How can I achieve that larger widths **produce a slider** (like display of a dataframe) so that I can make images as wide as I wish?

Comment: I think for (3) you simply have to double click onto the graph.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @JANO You're right, double clicking on the figure does solve my problem (3). Thanks! Any idea how to "edit the question" the way that the community bot demanded? Isn't my question already very specific?

Comment: You're welcome! I tried to answer the remainder as well. Regarding your post: I think you are fine and it will not be deleted. However, it is often preferred if you only include one question/topic per post as (3) is not related to dataframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You solved (1) already by deciding to display the dataframe with the method in (2). Using `print` to display a dataframe is not very useful in my opinion.

(2): The `display(df)` automatically utilizes white spaces to wrap cell content. I did not find a pandas option to disable this behavior. Luckily, someone else had the same problem already and another person provided a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52386540/7947994).

You have to change the style properties of your dataframe. For this you use the [`Styler`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html), which holds the styled dataframe. I made a short example from which you can copy the line:

```
import pandas as pd

# Construct data frame content
long_text = 'abcabcabc ' * 10
long_row = [long_text for _ in range(45)]
long_table = [long_row for _ in range(15)]

# Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(long_table)


# Select data you want to output
# df_selected = df.head(5) # First five rows
# df_selected = df.tail(5) # Last five rows
df_selected = df.iloc[[1,3, 7]] # Select row 1,3 and 7

# Create styler of df_selected with changed style of white spaces 
dataframe_styler = df_selected.style.applymap(lambda x:'white-space:nowrap')

# Display styler
display(dataframe_styler)
```

Output:
[image]

(3) As I already mentioned in the comment, you simply have to double click onto the diagram and it is displayed with a slider.

Comment: Thank you, now it works for small dataframes. However, it displays *all* rows. For any larger dataframe, this is not usable. How can I turn truncation back on?

Comment: I am not sure what attributes the styler takes for truncation, but I am sure there is some way. However, I think the easiest solution to limit the displayed rows is to create a reduced dataframe that only contains the data you want to display. I edited the answer to only output three specific rows of the dataframe.